# ImmutableJS - pushing into a nested array

Tags: javascript, immutability, immutable.js

```
const List = Immutable.List;
const items = [
  { id: 1, subList: [] }, 
  { id: 2, subList: [] }, 
  { id: 3, subList: [] }
];
const newItem = { name: "sublist item" };

let collection = List(items);

collection = collection.updateIn([0, 'subList'], function (items) {
  return items.concat(newItem)
});
```

https://jsbin.com/midimupire/edit?html,js,console

Results in:

> Error: invalid keyPath

I think that perhaps I need to set subList as a `List()`; I get the same error when trying this.

Comment: Which key is causing the error?

Comment: Difficult to tell (https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/635). I know from running this locally with the most up to date Immutable, the issue is [0] cannot be Set

Comment: Change the `updateIn` to `getIn`, and try removing the "subList" key. Does it return the first map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to return `collection` with the first element as:

```
{
  id : 1,
  subList: [
    {name: "sublist item"}
  ]
}
```

To do this we'll need to make a few changes.

1. Use [`Immutable.fromJS`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS) to deeply convert the plain JS array of objects to an Immutable List of Maps
2. Use [`List.update()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/update) to return a new `List` with the updated value
3. Use [`Map.updateIn()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/updateIn) to return a new LMapist with the updated value

Here's the whole thing:

```js
const List = Immutable.List;
const items = [{
    id: 1,
    subList: []
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    subList: []
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    subList: []
  }
];
const newItem = {
  name: "sublist item"
};

let collection = Immutable.fromJS(items);

collection = collection.update(0, item => {
  return item.updateIn(['subList'], subList => {
    return subList.concat(newItem);
  });
});

console.log(collection)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.js"></script>
```

And the result:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "subList": [
      {
        "name": "sublist item"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "subList": []
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "subList": []
  }
]
```

**Update:** `List.updateIn()` can use an index as the keypath, so you can simplify this to the following:

```
collection = collection.updateIn([0, 'subList'], subList => {
  return subList.concat(newItem);
});
```

Like this:

```js
const List = Immutable.List;
const items = [{
    id: 1,
    subList: []
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    subList: []
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    subList: []
  }
];
const newItem = {
  name: "sublist item"
};

let collection = Immutable.fromJS(items);

collection = collection.updateIn([0, 'subList'], subList => {
  return subList.concat(newItem);
});

console.log(collection)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the object you got, update the subArray and return the whole object.

```
const List = Immutable.List;
const items = [
  { id: 1, subList: [] }, 
  { id: 2, subList: [] }, 
  {id: 3, subList: [] }
];
const newItem = { name: "sublist item" };

let collection = List(items);

collection = collection.update([0], function (obj) {
   obj.subList = obj.subList.concat(newItem)
   return obj;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn’t work because the elements of your `Immutable.List` are plain-old JavaScript objects (POJO), not `Immutable.Map`s, so `updateIn` doesn’t know how to work with them. You can either:

- Make the objects `Immutable.Map`s by using [`Immutable.fromJS`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS) instead of `Immutable.List` as the constructor to convert the entire object graph to Immutable objects. ([See JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/wuwucijeci/edit?html,js,console))
- Use `update([0])` instead of `updateIn` to just get the POJO and mutate it (as in @Navjot’s answer).